# Do unsynced Bitcoin ABC nodes send Bitcoin transactions instead of Bitcoin Cash transactions?

Tags: transactions, synchronization, bitcoin-cash

Bitcoin ABC is fully compatible to Bitcoin up to the fork. Does that mean that an unsynchronized Bitcoin ABC node sends Bitcoin transactions instead of Bitcoin Cash?

Comment: Perhaps my problem here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/57589/31364 ?

Comment: I wonder if the node is looking for the fork, and not finding it?

Comment: Yeah, sounds very likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Bitcoin ABC that is released before UAHF happened, sends Bitcoin-style transactions if it is not synced.

Proof: https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/commit/fda9dab6a9fba4a95aa2d9620f28b787efccf748

The current latest version always sends Bitcoin Cash transactions.

Proof: https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L2966